# "...: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Tags: bash, architecture

I'm trying to execute a bash command, but it gives me that answer *for every command I know*.

bash: /home/jb/bin/ls : impossible d'exécuter le fichier binaire : Erreur de format pour exec()

It would translate this way : "...: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 last year and it worked like a charm. I may have messed with something when trying to configure from that computer a raspberry/ARM.

I've looked for an answer on many forums, but the only thing I found is that my file is 32bits (not the case!).

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

EDIT 1:
my architecture is x86-64 with ubuntu 22.04

EDIT 2: Thanks to steeldriver, I understood my problem. I probably messed up when installing an ARM distribution on my RPI, and ended creating another "bin" folder with ARM architecture (probably). Also my PATH was changed.

I tried to correct it with export PATH=:... It works, but each time I open another shell, the faulty path (/home/jb/bin/) comes back. Anyone knows how to definitely cure that ??

Comment: Are you *trying* to execute `/home/jb/bin/ls` - or are you trying to execute `ls` and it just happens that `/home/jb/bin/` comes before `/bin` and `/usr/bin` in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: You did not mention the architexture of your machine, but you told you tried to configure a RaspberryPi (ARM) from it. I think you are trying to execute an ARM binary on an Intel/AMD x86 or x64 processor, or the other way around.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.